# c# en consola, While anidados, preguntas de salir si / no en sub menus y limites

Tags: c#

Bueno, mi problemática radica en las preguntas de los submenús, ya que cuando hace las preguntas, y regreso al menú respondiendo negativamente, cuando selecciono una opción que no esta en el rango en el menú principal, ejecuta una instrucción de texto en ciclo infinito(tipo matrix) y solo funciona la primera vez que ejecuto el programa.

PD: Soy estudiante de primer año, soy novato en esto, muchas gracias de antemano(ojala y me entienda

Código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace segundo
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int op = 0, colum, fil, colum2, fil2;
            string can = "";
            int con = 0;
            while (can != "no")
            {
                do
                { 

                    for (colum = 1; colum < 23; colum++)
                    {
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(15, colum);
                        Console.Write("*");
                    }
                    for (colum2 = 1; colum2 < 23; colum2++)
                    {
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(60, colum2);
                        Console.Write("*");
                    }
                    for (fil = 16; fil < 60; fil++)
                    {
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(fil, 1);
                        Console.Write("*");
                    }
                    for (fil2 = 16; fil2 < 60; fil2++)
                    {
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(fil2, 22);
                        Console.Write("*");
                    }

                    Console.SetCursorPosition(30, 3);
                    Console.WriteLine("MENU DE OPCIONES");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 6);
                    Console.WriteLine("1-Cálculo de edad");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 8);
                    Console.WriteLine("2-Masa Corporal IMC");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 10);
                    Console.WriteLine("3-Diguito Verificador de la Cédula");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 12);
                    Console.WriteLine("4-Conversor");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 14);
                    Console.WriteLine("5-Reemplazador de Letras");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 16);
                    Console.WriteLine("6-Salir");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(35, 18);
                    Console.Write("Elija Una opción: ");
                    op = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    do
                    {
                        switch (op)
                        {
                            case 1:

                                int dian, mesn, añon, diac, mesac, añoac, diar, mesr, añor;
                                Console.Clear();
                                Console.SetCursorPosition(30, 3);
                                Console.WriteLine("Diguito Verificador de la Cédula");
                                Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 6);
                                Console.Write("Ingrese el día de su nacimiento: ");
                                dian = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                                Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 8);
                                Console.Write("Ingrese el mes en el que nacio: ");
                                mesn = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                                Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 10);
                                Console.Write("Ingrese el año de su nacimiento: ");
                                añon = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                                Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 12);
                                Console.Write("Ingrese el dia actual: ");
                                diac = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                                Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 14);
                                Console.Write("Ingrese el mes actual: ");
                                mesac = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                                Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 16);
                                Console.Write("Ingrese el año actual: ");
                                añoac = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                                //Condicion
                                if (dian != 0)
                                {
                                    diac = diac + 30;
                                    mesac = mesac - 1;
                                }
                                diar = diac - dian;
                                if (mesn != 0)
                                {
                                    mesac = mesac + 12;
                                    añoac = añoac - 1;
                                }
                                mesr = mesac - mesn;
                                añor = añoac - añon;
                                Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 20);
                                Console.Write("Tu edad actual es: {0} años, {1} meses, con {2} días.", añor, mesr, diar);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                Console.Clear();
                                Double alt, peso, imc;
                                Console.SetCursorPosition(30, 3);
                                Console.Write("Indice de masa corporal (IMC)");
                                Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 6);
                                Console.Write("Ingrese tu estatura (Metros): ");
                                alt = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                                Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 8);
                                Console.Write("Ingresa tu peso (kg): ");
                                peso = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                                imc = peso / (alt * alt);
                                Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 14);
                                Console.Write("Su IMC es: {0}", imc);
                                Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 16);
                                if (alt != 0)
                                {
                                    if (imc < 18)
                                    {
                                        Console.Write(" Usted posee un bajo de lo normal, desnutrición");
                                    }
                                    else if (imc >= 18 && imc < 25)
                                    {
                                        Console.Write("Usted posee un peso optimo, esta saludable");
                                    }
                                    else if (imc <= 25 && imc < 27)
                                    {
                                        Console.Write(" Usted posee sobrepeso, advertencia");
                                    }
                                    else if (imc >= 27)
                                    {
                                        Console.Write("Usted posee Obesidad, No esta nada saludable.");
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                            case 6:
                                if (op == 6)
                                {
                                    return;
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                                Console.Write(" solo se admiten numeros del 1 al 6, ingrese opcion correcta");
                                break;
                        }
                        con = op;
                        if (con <= 6)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("¿De nuevo? si/no: ");
                            can = Console.ReadLine();
                            if (can == "si")
                            {
                                Console.Clear();
                            }
                        }
                    } while (can== "no");

            con = op;
                if (con <= 6)
                {

                    Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 20);
                    Console.Write("¿Desea Continuar con el menu principal? si/no: ");
                    can = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (can == "si")
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                    }
                }
                } while (can == "no");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira esta [guia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Has puesto demasiado codigo como para que podamos entender que pasa. reduce el codigo a la parte estrictamente necesaria, y si sabes mas o menos donde esta el problema resaltalo.

Answer (score 0):

Modifica tu primer `while` para que la condición sea

```
while (can == "si");
```

y el segundo (el del final) con otro

```
while (can == "si");
```

Esto es porque ambas condiciones están mal, un "no" hace que regrese al principio del ciclo; en el primer caso vuelve a evaluar la opción original y en el segundo le dices que regrese al menú (al principio del `while`) cuando el usuario escriba que *"no"* quiere regresar al menú.

Comment: Ise esta modificacion al programa (el resto sigue igual), en cuanto a las preguntas del menu, ya estan bien, todas funciona correctamente, solo que al agregar un default para que apareciece una leyenda cada vez que ingresen un numero fuera del rango del menu principal (Numeros del 1 al 6)

Comment: para por ejemplo si ingresan el 7 les aparesca ese texto y dejase ingresar opcion nuevamente, lo cual solo funciona 1 vez, por que si respondo negativamente (despues de hacer un calculo en un submenu) salgo nuevamente al menu principal y ingreso un numero fuera de rango, hay un buche interminable tipo matriz de ese texto de advertencia.

Comment: `código`  if (con <= 6)
                {

                    Console.SetCursorPosition(20, 20);
                    Console.Write("¿Desea Continuar con el menu principal? si/no: ");
                    can = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (can == "si")
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                    }
                        else
                        {
                            Environment.Exit(0);
                        }
                }
                } while (can == "no");